# How to mock AWS S3 getObject with sinon

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-s3, sinon

I'm trying to unit test a restify route that returns an S3 object from a bucket

my route is:

```js
module.exports = function(server) {
  server.get('/configs/:version', (req, res, next) => {
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    const params = {
      Bucket: 'testBucket',
      Key: 'testKey'
    };

    function send(data, next) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
      res.status(200);
      res.send(data.Body);
      next();
    }

    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => (err) ? next(err) : send(data, next));
  });
};
```

For my unit test I've been trying to mock the S3 constructor so I can stub `getObject` and failing miserably.

```js
describe('#configs', () => {
  let req;
  let res;
  let next;
  let server;
  let config;
  let AWS;
  let S3;
  let route;

  beforeEach(() => {
    req = {
      params: {
        version: 'testVersion'
      }
    };

    res = {
      send: sinon.spy(),
    };

    next = sinon.spy();

    server = {
      get: sinon.stub(),
    };

    config = {
      get: sinon.stub(),
    }

    AWS = () => {
      return {
        S3: () => {
          return {
            getObject: sinon.stub()
          }
        }
      }
    }

    route = proxyquire(process.cwd() + '/lib/routes/configs/get', {
      'configs.js': config,
      'aws-sdk': AWS,
    });

    route(server);
  });

  describe('#GET', () => {
    it('Should register configs get route', () => {
      let s3 = sinon.createStubInstance(AWS.S3, {
        getObject: sinon.stub(),
      });

      server.get.callArgWith(1, req, res, next);
      expect(server.get).calledOnce.calledWith('/configs/:version');
      expect(s3.getObject).calledOnce.calledWith({
        Bucket: 'testBucket',
        Key: 'testKey'
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But I getting this error:
`TypeError: undefined is not a spy or a call to a spy!` on the getObject method.
After reading sinon docs over and over again I can't understand how to mock the constructor, how can I stub the getObject method so I can make sure it's being called correctly and it's returns so I know it's responses are being treated correctly Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Finally made my mocks work, the issue was that I was mocking AWS as a function not has an object, it's S3 that needs to be mocked as a function, because it's S3 that needs to be instantiated. This is how the mock should look like:

```
function S3() { 
  return s3;
}

s3 = {
  getObject: sinon.stub(),
  putObject: sinon.stub()
};

AWS = {
  config: {
    update: sinon.stub()
  },
  S3: S3
};
```

Like this if one needs to mock putObject, he just needs for example do this: 
s3.putObject.callsArgWith(1, err, data);

Comment: i have tried the above code but its not working .can you provide a example in brief way ?

Comment: Yes, this code doesn't work. I'll correct the answer.

Comment: TypeError: AWS.S3 is not a constructor

Comment: Remember you don't to instantiate on your tests, it's already being instantiated on your code, in fact you want to mock the methods of that same instance.
But anyway this code doesn't reflect my final solution, I'll fix it...

Answer (score 0):

```
const getObjectStub = AWS.S3.prototype.getObject = Sinon.stub();
    getObjectStub.yields(null, {
    AcceptRanges: "bytes", 
    ContentLength: 3191, 
    ContentType: "image/jpeg", 
    Metadata: {
    }, 
    TagCount: 2, 
    VersionId: "null"
   }
);
```

Comment: Hi there, I see that you're new here! Please, when you answer a question, provide context of your answer, and not just a code block, that way, the person asking can learn why the issue was occurring.